# Prevent android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED on Package Update

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, manifest

I have registered a global **Broadcast Receiver** in Manifest which shows a notification when the user uninstalls a package.

```
 <receiver android:name=".YourReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="com.times.REFRESH_INSTALL_FLAG" />

            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The problem is that when some package is updating from Play Store the action
**android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED**  and **android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED** are called one after another.

The problem is that I am unable to differentiate whether a package is uninstalled or updating.

One of the way is to wait till we receive **PACKAGE_ADDED** for the same package name and then dismiss a notification.

Is there any other correct method to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it myself! Distinguish by checking whether the received package name is installed or not!

Answer (score 2):

You could also check the [EXTRA_REPLACING](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_REPLACING) extra on the intent (if it is a `PACKAGE_REMOVED` intent).

> public static final String EXTRA_REPLACING
>
> Used as a boolean extra field in ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED intents to
> indicate that this is a replacement of the package, so this broadcast
> will immediately be followed by an add broadcast for a different
> version of the same package.